# LINQ: How do I compare two elements?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings and if one element is a substring of another element, I want to remove that shorter element.

So,

```
{abc, def, ghi, ab, cd, ef} => {abc, def, ghi, cd}
```

I tried:

```
list = list.Where((x, y) => x.Item1 != y.Item1 && x.Item1.Contains(y.Item1) == false);
```

but somehow `y` is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The overload of `Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) that you used is for filtering with an element and the index. You need to use the "regular" `Where`, like this:

```
var res = list.Where(x => !list.Any(y => x != y && y.Contains(x)));
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/o6inHr)